# host target development model

Tags: embedded, target, cross-compiling, host

I am quite new to the embedded linux programming and did not really understand this concept very well.

Can anyone explain the essence of the "host-target" relation? Is this model only specific to the "cross-compilation"? Is it used just because "executable code will be run on another enviroment"? and what matters with the linux kernel on the target? E.g., the "building the embedded linux system" book mentioned this, but did not explain its motivation or goal of this type of development.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where -- specifically -- did you see the phrase? What are you reading?  What toolkit will you be using?  Can you provide a link or a reference.  It's easier to answer if you know what you're looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'motivation' for this model is that seldom is an embedded target a suitable platform for development.  It may be resource constrained, have no operating system, have no compiler that will run on the target, have no filesystem for source files, have no keyboard or display, no networking, and may be relatively slow or anything else you might need to develop effectively.

If your embedded system is suited to running Linux, it is possible that not all of the above limitations apply, but almost certainly enough of them to make you want to avoid developng directly on the target.  If this were not so, they it hardly qualifies as an embedded system perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.landley.net/writing/docs/cross-compiling.html

Seems pretty clear.  What **specific** questions do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Linux since its very origin was written in very portable way. It runs on a whole range of machines with very different CPUs, and it is considered the Good Thing to write in a portable way, so that, for example, package maintainer can easily port your program to some embedded ARM or Cygwin, or Amiga, or...

So, yes, the model is "only" specific to cross-compilation, but actually about every compilation on Linux is a (variant of) cross-compilation, just that by default build, host and target are automatically set to the same value, the same as the machine you run on.

Still, even then, you can take a Linux-i386 compiled compiler, sources for it, and "cross-compile" it for Linux-amd64. And the resulting binary will run much faster on a 64bit CPU.

It IS quite essential in embedded programming though. Mostly because you write programs for weak CPUs that are not capable of running a compiler or would run it at a snail pace. So you take a cross-compiler on a fast CPU (say, some multi-core Intel) and cross-compile for the embedded CPU (say, some low-end ARM).

"In different environment" is putting things very mildly. What you're doing when cross-compiling for embedded is working with entirely different instruction set, different memory access modes, different resource access methods and so on and so on. A machine of entirely different construction than the build host. Your build host may be a Windows PC running Cygwin. Your target may be a chip inside a smartphone. The binary will look nothing like the Cygwin .exe files.

As a direct consequence, -everything- must be compiled for the target from scratch. The kernel, the system utilities, the system libraries, all the tools the target must be running. Thing is, if the target is a ticket selling booth, there is really no sense cross-compiling Eclipse, GCC and Gnome for it, then developing in "local" environment, typing your code on a ticket booth keyboard. Instead, you just cross-compile the essentials of the OS, and your specific applications. You keep the development environment on the build machine, and cross-compile everything you need on the embedded device.

[in practice, you get a Linux distro for the target, and just compile whatever you need modified].